# Does Ember View support focus out on view container?

Tags: ember.js

It seems that focusOut is not triggered on container element (e.g `DIV`) in all browsers. I tested in in IE11 and it worked but using newest Chrome the event is not fired.

This example shows what I look for: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xeyasane/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focusOut` is generally not used for `div` elements (although I have seen some hack implementations...). If you register the view using `tagName: 'input'`, it works as expected.

Here is a working version of your jsbin that uses focusOut: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xeyasane/4/edit

Here is a list of Ember event names: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-names

Comment: Thanks. I worked around it registering `click` on body (`.one()`) and using event namespace (e.g `click.foo`). Perhaps Ember `rootElement` would have been better than `body` but I didn't notice any problems yet. Generally what I looked for was to handle saving object when it moves from editing to preview mode (inplace edit fields).